# Hide keyboard when we scroll with TableView after we searched

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I want to hide the keyboard when I scroll on TableView. That means, I search for an item and I see the results, when I scroll on the TableView the keyboard will hide or dismiss. Look at this image.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to track the action that runs when the tableView is being scrolled. `UITableView` is the subclass of `UIScrollView`. So, you can use all the methods from `UIScrollViewDelegate` for your table.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
        [textfield resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This will work.

Answer (score 5):

Set up the scrollview delegate in your header then make it so when

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView*)scrollview{
[self.textfield resignFirstResponder];}
```

and when he stops scrolling

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView*)scrollview willDecelerate:YES{
//open keyboard back up}
```

edit:
my bad, i confused scrollview and tableview. disregard anything up there, i cant find anything for your problem

Comment: You can still implement scrollview delegate methods in a tableview delegate.

Comment: Yes @darvids0n is correct, `UITableViewDelegate` extends `UIScrollViewDelegate`, so your answer is fine.